# Fixing a YouTube regex in a replace filter

Tags: filter, regex, replace

I need to take the dominant YouTube URL schemas and convert them into a YouTube embed URL of the form:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID
```

I know there are technically loads of possible YouTube URL variants but I'm really only interested in:

1. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvqY2NcBWI8`
2. `https://youtu.be/MvqY2NcBWI8`

…where either of those could be extended with optional parameters.

So I'm doing this to extract the `vidId`, which works for **1**:

```
{% set vidUrl = block.videoUrl %}
{% set vidId  = vidUrl|replace('/^http.*\\?v=([^\\&]+)(\\&.*)?$/', '$1') %}
```

…and then this for **2**:

```
{% set vidId = vidId ? vidId : vidUrl|replace('/^http.*\\.be\\/([^\\?]+)(\\?.*)?$/', '$1') %}
```

…which *doesn’t work*.

And yet when I replace `\\` with `\` and test it in my text editor it *does* work.

This should capture the id up to the beginning of any query string…

```
([^\\?]+)
```

…and this should discard any parameters which follow…

```
(\\?.*)?$
```

Shouldn't it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Doh! It was my ternary logic that was failing not the regex. I’m now doing this:

```
{% set vidUrl = block.videoUrl %}

{% if 'youtu' in vidUrl %}
    {# Check for an 'embed' URL which may need cleaning #}
    {% set vidId = 'embed' in vidUrl ? vidUrl|replace('/^http.*embed\\/([^\\?]+)(\\?.*)?$/', '$1') : null %}

    {# Check for a 'watch' URL which may need cleaning #}
    {% set vidId = 'watch' in vidUrl ? vidUrl|replace('/^http.*\\?v=([^\\&]+)(\\&.*)?$/', '$1') : vidId %}

    {# Check for a 'youtu.be' URL which may need cleaning #}
    {% set vidId = '.be/' in vidUrl ? vidUrl|replace('/^http.*\\.be\\/([^\\?]+)(\\?.*)?$/', '$1') : vidId %}

    {% set srcUrl = vidId ? "https://www.youtube.com/embed/#{vidId}" : null %}
{% endif %}

{% if srcUrl %}
    {# Write the iframe #}
{% else %}
    {# Write some help for logged in CMS folks #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Maybe in your case it's overkill, but a custom Twig variable would be perfect for this job. Also the oEmbed plugin is good at this.

Comment: Thanks @gioppe, [oEmbed](https://plugins.craftcms.com/oembed) does look like a cool plugin. I will check it out.